# Purpose of template function with enum type

Tags: c++, templates

I have seen code that looks something like this:

```
enum Type { A, B, C };

template <Type>
void foo();

void foo<A>() { // code here }
void foo<B>() { // code here }
void foo<C>() { // code here }
```

Does this offer any advantages over just giving the three functions different names?

Comment: You example is probably simplified too much.

Comment: It lets you select one of the functions using a value of `Type` known at compile time.

Comment: Define _advantages_. It's pretty opinion-based as it is your question.